# What is meant by Lyapunov functional?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In the context of variational calculus, what is meant by 'Lyapunov functional'?

Frankly speaking, in calculus of variation, we are searching for some $u(x)$ to put in $F(x,u(x),u'(x))$ in order to minimize
$$
J(u):=\int_a^b F(x,u(x),u'(x))\, dx.
$$

But what is meant by 'Lyapunov functional' in this context?